# Help with binomial expansion exercise

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have missed a few lessons in school and I had to learn this topic pretty much on my own. And now I am stuck on this question while preparing for the test:
"Find c given the expansion $(1+cx)(1+x)^4$ includes the term $22x^3$"
I am pretty stumped because I have no idea on where to start

Comment: [Expand the polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Collect%5B+Expand%5B%281%2Bc+x%29%281%2Bx%29%5E4%5D%2C+x+%5D): you can see the coefficient of $x^3$ now, as a function of $c$. It remains to find the $c$ for which this coefficient equals $22$.

Answer (score 2):

$$(1+cx)(1+x)^4=(1+cx)(1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4)=$$
$$=1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4+cx+4cx^2+6cx^3+4cx^4+cx^5=$$
$$=1+(4+c)x+(6+4c)x^2+(4+6c)x^3+(1+4c)x^4+cx^5=$$

$$(4+6c)x^3=22x^3\Rightarrow 4+6c=22\Rightarrow c=3$$

Answer (score 1):

We are interested in the coefficient on $x^3$.  Think about how you would expand $(1+cx)(1 + x)^4$ to get an $x^3$ term.

Let's first expand $(1+x)^4$.  From this, there are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to get an $x^3$ term and $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to get an $x^2$ term.  Therefore, the $x^3$ term and $x^2$ term will have coefficients $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ and $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ respectively.

Now we can multiply these terms by either the $1$ or the $cx$ terms from $(1+cx)$ to yield the final $x^3$ term in the complete expansion.  First, we pick up a coefficient of $4$ by multiplying $1$ with $4x^3$.  Next, we pick up a coefficient of $6c$ by multiplying $cx$ with $6x^2$.  Combining, our final result is $(4 + 6c)x^3$, and the coefficient must equal $22$...

Comment: Oops, I accidentally swapped a $4$ and a $6$ in my original answer and didn't notice until hours later.  Fixed!